# loop over JSON data from AJAX Success?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I receive a Json output from PHP page like this

```html
[{"x":"2018-03-20","y":1,"z":7},{"x":"2018-03-22","y":31,"z":5},{"x":"2018-03-25","y":7,"z":21}]
```

How can I loop over the results so that I would have access to each of the elements? I have tried something like below but this does not seem to be working.

```js
function LoadResultMorris()
{
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'admin/data.php',
    data: {type1: 'search1'},
    success: function(data){
$.each(data.data, function(key, value) {
    alert(data[key]);
    alert(data[value]);
});
        }
});

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop all list of objects in the following format

```
$.each(JSON.parse(data.data), function(key,obj) {
   //Access Property in format Object.Atribute
   alert(obj.x); //X Atribute
   alert(obj.y); //Y Atribute
   alert(obj.z); //Z Atribute
});
```

Comment: Thank you ! I tried your code like below but its not working for me, I can't see the error
`function LoadResultMorris()
{
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'admin/data.php',
    data: {type1: 'search1'},
    success: function(data){
$.each(data.data, function(key,obj) {
   alert(obj.x); 
   alert(obj.y); 
   alert(obj.z); 
});
        }
});

}`

Comment: What does the post method returns as a result? Is data.data a json type or a string? If your response is of type string try using $.each(JSON.parse(data.data), function ........

Comment: It return a Json type,  I noticed that I had i mistake in may code, I replace data.data by data but the issue still persist
`function LoadResultMorris()
{
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'admin/data.php',
    data: {type1: 'search1'},
    success: function(data){
 $.each(data, function(key,obj) {
   //Access Property in format Object.Atribute
   alert(obj.x); //X Atribute
   alert(obj.y); //Y Atribute
   alert(obj.z); //Z Atribute
}); 
}
});

}`

Comment: what error message do you get after applying this code? @marie_dev

Comment: Did you se the console for any error message? Are you sure data.data has content ? Try using console.log(data.data) to see the content of the array. @marie_dev

Comment: the error in the console :
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in [{"x":"2018-03-20","y":1,"z":7},{"x":"2018-03-22","y":31,"z":5},{"x":"2018-03-25","y":7,"z":21}]

Comment: The data.data is of type string try converting to json array using JSON.parse() as below $.each(JSON.parse(data.data), function(key,obj) {
   //Access Property in format Object.Atribute
   alert(obj.x); //X Atribute
   alert(obj.y); //Y Atribute
   alert(obj.z); //Z Atribute
}); 
Share

Answer (score 0):

Given that the data structure you're working with is a plain array of objects, jQuery isn't really necessary here. You can use a standard `forEach()` loop, accessing the properties of the object by name. Try this:

```js
// mock AJAX response:
let data = [{"x":"2018-03-20","y":1,"z":7},{"x":"2018-03-22","y":31,"z":5},{"x":"2018-03-25","y":7,"z":21}];

// inside the AJAX success handler:
data.forEach(object => {
  console.log(object.x, object.y, object.z);
});
```